# Getting one row/cell for the same sender in conversation list

Tags: php, yii2

I have a message center in my website where the conversation list continuously adds a new row/cell for the same sender as you keep the conversation with the same sender. In other words if you receive 4 messages from the same sender in the conversation list you will have 4 row/cell of the same sender from whom you receive the message. However I would like to have 1 row/cell in the conversation list for the same sender no matter how many times the sender writes.

Below it is related code from the message controller.

```
// get recent messages to show in left column

$recent = Message::find()
                ->with('sentFrom')
                ->where(['sent_to' => Yii::$app->user->identity->id])
                ->andfilterWhere([
                                    'or', 
                                    ['like', 'subject', $search_subject],
                                    ['like', 'sent_from', $search_sender],
                ])
                ->orderBy('created_at DESC')
                ->limit(Yii::$app->params['message_chat']['recent_limit'])
                ->all();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try to use groupBy statement (something like this)::

```
$recent = Message::find()
    ->with('sentFrom')
    ->where(['sent_to' => Yii::$app->user->identity->id])
    ->andfilterWhere([
        'or',
        ['like', 'subject', $search_subject],
        ['like', 'sent_from', $search_sender],
    ])
    ->orderBy('created_at DESC')
    ->limit(Yii::$app->params['message_chat']['recent_limit'])
    ->groupBy(['sentFrom.id'])
    ->all();
```

Comment: b.tokman, thank you very much for your answer, I appreciate it. I'd tried as you suggested but it showed "database exception", I don't know why. Just a note, my website is in Yii2 faramewor.

Comment: I think the problem with group by statement, ['sentFrom.id'] - change the  sentFrom to right table name from sentFrom relation and change id to table primary key. The result would be something like [your_realated_table_name.primary_key]